# Variable scope & Callback woes

Tags: json, node.js, scope, callback

This program is reading through the nested object searching for a specific key & values. Once this data is found it has to initiate callback to send back the data. The object looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "joel",
    "title": "CTO",
    "edu": {
        "school": "RMB",
        "college": "GNK",
        "pg": "CDAC",
        "extract": "This is a large text ..."
    }
}
```

Here as I come from synchronous programming background I am not able to understand when I have to initiate the callback and also ensure variables are in scope

```
function parseData(str, callback) {

   function recursiveFunction(obj) {
       var keysArray = Object.keys(obj);

       for (var i = 0; i < keysArray.length; i++) {
           var key = keysArray[i];
           var value = obj[key];

           if (value === Object(value)) {
               recursiveFunction(value);
           }
           else {
               if (key == 'title') {
                   var title = value;
               }

               if (key == 'extract') {
                   var extract = value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
                   callback(null, JSON.stringify({title: title, text: extract}));
               }
           }
       }
   }

   recursiveFunction(str, callback(null, JSON.stringify({title: title, text: extract})));
};
```

when this code is executed we get following error

```
/parseData.js:29
   recursiveFunction(str, callback(null, JSON.stringify({title: title, text: extract})));
                                                            ^
ReferenceError: title is not defined
```

Comment: It's very hard to answer this question without seeing your input object and the desired result. As it stands right now, the function does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Tomalak the JSON data would be like this

    {
      "name": "joel",
      "title": "CTO",
      "edu": {
        "school": "RMB",
        "college": "GNK",
        "pg": "CDAC",
        "extract": "This is a large text ..."
       }
    }

and the desired result will be

{
  "title": "CTO",
  "extract": "This is a large text ..."
}

Comment: And what's the desired behavior/outcome? You did not specify what the function is supposed to do. Also, as @Svabael states below, so far this has nothing to do with asynchronous programming.

Comment: The program should scan through the nested JSON and pick values of 2 keys and once done return back this object to calling module.

Also I am not sure if this is a right way to do a callback 

if (key == 'extract') {
                   var extract = value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
                   callback(null, JSON.stringify({title: title, text: extract}));
               }

as it seems that the flow is abruptly exiting recursiveFunction. In synchronous programming we know exactly when both the values are available and when to send back.

Comment: Again: There is no asynchronous component in the code above. All of this is perfectly synchronous, single-threaded code. How many objects with the `title` and `extract` properties are there? One? Or could it be any number? Is `extract` always a child of `edu`? How deeply nested can this be (in other words, is a recursive function necessary at all?)

Comment: There is only one object for both title and extract. Extract is not always a child of edu and so we need recursive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So you want a function that retrieves the first property named `title` and the first property named `extract` from a nested object, no matter how deeply nested these properties are.

"Extract a property value from an object" is basically is a task in its own right, we could write a function for it.

There are three cases to handle:

1. The argument is not an object - return `undefined`
2. The argument contains the key in question - return the associated value
3. Otherwise, recurse into the object and repeat steps 1 and 2 - return according result

It could look like this:

```
function pluck(obj, searchKey) {
    var val;

    if (!obj || typeof obj !== "object") return;
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(searchKey)) return obj[searchKey];
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        if (val) return;
        val = pluck(obj[key], searchKey);
    });
    return val;
}
```

Now we can call `pluck()` on any object and with any key and it will return to us the first value it finds anywhere in the object.

Now the rest of your task becomes very easy:

```
var obj = {
    "name": "joel",
    "title": "CTO",
    "edu": {
        "school": "RMB",
        "college": "GNK",
        "pg": "CDAC",
        "extract": "This is a large text ..."
    }
}

var data = {
    title: pluck(obj, "title"),
    text: pluck(obj, "extract")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This function that you 've posted above has nothing to do with async programming. I will respond in the context of the chunk of code that you 've posted. The error that you have is because you are calling the `recursiveFunction(str, callback(null, JSON.stringify({title: title, text: extract})));` but the `title` variable is nowhere defined. I can see a definition of the `title` but it is in the the context of the `recursiveFunction` function. The variables that you define in there are not visible outside of the scope of that function and that's why you have this error.

You are trying to do something strange in this line:
`recursiveFunction(str, callback(null, JSON.stringify({title: title, text: extract})));`

This line will invoke the callback and will pass in the recursiveFunction the results of this function. I would expect to see something like that in this line:
`recursiveFunction(str, callback);`